# How to begin reading a file using the readline module from line 2?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, readline

How do you read a file from line 2? I'm stuck in a problem where the first line is of no consequence and I should be able to read from the second line of the file? How do I go about it using the readline module?

Answer (score 0):

Use event **line** to capture every line break:
https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_event_line

```
const fs = require('fs')
const readline = require('readline')

const file = readline.createInterface({
  input: fs.createReadStream('{your_file_path}')
})

let index = 1
file.on('line', (line) => {
  if (index === 2) {
    console.log(line)
    // to what you want with data
  }
  index++
})
```